How I create an optional row in an InfoBox in MediaWiki?
I want to create a row that doesn't appear if it's not specified. I have the following around the row in question:
{{#if:{{{author|}}}|
|-
| '''Author'''
| {{{author}}}
}}

But in practice, adding 'author' doesn't make anything appear, am I writing this incorrectly?

EDIT: thanks for the help, updated it to be this:
{{!}}{{#if:{{{author|}}}|<nowiki />
{{!}}-
{{!}} '''Author'''
{{!}} {{{author|Value}}}
}}


You need to escape | as {{!}} in the table markup. As it is now, MediaWiki sees an #if call where the second argument is just a newline.

here is an example on how to add conditional rows to a wiki table, maybe this also works for the infoBox template
{|class="wikitable" style="float:right; margin-left: 10px; border: #94bf88 thin solid;"
|+
! colspan="2" style="background-color: #d9ffda; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; color: black; border: none;"  |Artikelinformationen {{
#if: {{{artikelthumbnail|}}}|<nowiki />
{{!}}-
{{!}} colspan="2" style="border: none" {{!}} {{{artikelthumbnail}}}
}}
|-
|-
| colspan="2" style= "text-align: center; border: none; font-size: 15px;"|'''Basisdaten''' {{
#if: {{{artikeltitel|}}}|<nowiki />
{{!}}-
{{!}} style="border: none" {{!}} '''Artikeltitel:'''
{{!}} style="width:200px; border: none;" {{!}} {{{artikeltitel}}} }}{{
#if: {{{veröffentlichungsdatum|}}}|<nowiki />
{{!}}-
{{!}} style="border: none" {{!}} '''Veröffentlichung:'''
{{!}} style="width:200px; border: none;" {{!}} {{{veröffentlichungsdatum}}}
}}
|}

taken from Mediawiki display table row only if value is present
